# jquery - colorbox - adding a function to the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, mbox

I have a "quick view" feature that captures a dynamic URL also known as "qvURL" and creates a colorbox with it via:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".quickview_btn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");
            $.colorbox({"href": qvURL})
        });
        $.colorbox.resize();
    });
</script>
```

Now. I need to make some changes in the child window - but it seems the AJAX or whatever is wiping out the entire DOM and anything I load from the parent window doesn't reflect.

For instance - let's say I just want to add a div that says qwerty!
[I'm actually wanting to create an mbox around a Call To Action]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Please note - the URLs it's loading is content that I can not manipulate - so it has to be done in the parent window.

Thanks!

Please see below for my full snippet:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.quickview_btn').click(function(){




  //Quickview tracking
  $('.quickview').attr('id', 'quickviewClicked-area');

  mboxDefine('quickviewClicked-area','quickviewClicked','clicked=Y');

$( 'div.quickview' ).bind( 'click', function() {
  console.log('clicked!');
  product = $(this).children().attr('href');
  console.log(product)

    mboxUpdate('quickviewClicked', "link="+product);  
 });



//thumbnail add to cart tracking




$('div.add-to-cart').attr('id', 'ThumbnailAddToCart-area');

mboxDefine('ThumbnailAddToCart-area','ThumbnailAddToCartClicked','clicked=Y');

$( 'div.qlBtns' ).bind( 'click', function() {
;


    mboxUpdate('ThumbnailAddToCartClicked', "clicked=Y");  
    console.log('mbox updated!')
});


});

});

/*
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(qvURL).$colorbox({
            iframe : true,
            frastIframe: false,
            onComplete: function(){
                $('.name').html('yeah you got it');
            }
        });
    });
    */
</script>
```

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.quickview_btn').click(function() {



      //Quickview tracking
      $('.quickview').attr('id', 'quickviewClicked-area');

      mboxDefine('quickviewClicked-area', 'quickviewClicked', 'clicked=Y');

      $('div.quickview').bind('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked!');
        product = $(this).children().attr('href');
        console.log(product)

        mboxUpdate('quickviewClicked', "link=" + product);
      });



      //thumbnail add to cart tracking




      $('div.add-to-cart').attr('id', 'ThumbnailAddToCart-area');

      mboxDefine('ThumbnailAddToCart-area', 'ThumbnailAddToCartClicked', 'clicked=Y');

      $('div.qlBtns').bind('click', function() {;


        mboxUpdate('ThumbnailAddToCartClicked', "clicked=Y");
        console.log('mbox updated!')
      });


    });

  });

/*
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(qvURL).$colorbox({
            iframe : true,
            frastIframe: false,
            onComplete: function(){
                $('.name').html('yeah you got it');
            }
        });
    });
 */
< /script>
```

Comment: Add it on Plunker/Fiddle and I can help you ;)

Comment: Hmm - it's a bit hard to do that since I'm injecting the code onto a page - that loads the call to action.

Comment: by child window I assume you mean the contents of the colorbox?  But if that content is out of your control what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have the HTML of said parent page? Are those 2 scripts the same thing or is there a small difference I do not readily see? Is the parent and child page in the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

I see this line in your code:

```
  $.colorbox({"href": qvURL})
```

and my first question is whether or not that selector is enough. Mind you I am more a middle-ware than a client-side guru, but from my knowledge of jQuery, that selector won't do anything because jQuery can't tell what you mean. See how you used the quotes in the assignment of the click function?

```
 $(".quickview_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
```

if you used $("#colorbox") to get the object (if that is its id) or $(".colorbox" if is is a a class you are targeting.
(I am not an expert, as I said, but those who are agree:

> ```
> $(".someClass") selects all elements with class name someClass
> $("#testButton") selects the element with the id value of testButton
> ```
>
> -- Courtesy of the [DZone jQuery Ref Card](https://dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors) at https://dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors

So it may be that everything else is fine, you just aren't passing your code anything to hook into the colorbox object.

Comment: Hi Joseph!

thank you so much - the selector does work correctly at the moment - please see the link below (hover over image and the "quick view") is that selector